# JS function doesn't pass the exact value to a form

Tags: javascript, forms

I have this js function:

```
function createFormAndSubmit(val){

{% for user in users %}

 var submitForm = document.createElement("form_user_{{ user.id }}");
 document.body.appendChild(submitForm);
 submitForm.method = "POST";

 var newid = document.createElement("input");
 newid.type = "hidden";
 newid.value = "{{ user.id }}";
 submitForm.appendChild(newid);

 var newperm = document.createElement("input");
 newperm.type = "radio";
 newperm.value = val;
 submitForm.appendChild(newperm);

 submitForm.action= "/networks/{{ net.id }}/sensors/{{ sens.id }}/rights";
 document.forms['form_user_{{ user.id }}'].submit();
 //submitForm.submit();

{% end %}

}
```

that it's called by this html element:

```
{% if users %}

        <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <strong>All users</strong>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="radio inline" onclick="createFormAndSubmit('0');">
                <input type="radio" name="permsall" id="all_0" value="0">
                None
              </label>
              <label class="radio inline" onclick="createFormAndSubmit('1');">
                <input type="radio" name="permsall" id="all_1" value="1">
                Read
              </label>
              <label class="radio inline" onclick="createFormAndSubmit('4');">
                <input type="radio" name="permsall" id="all_4" value="4">
                Read + Commands
              </label>
            </td>

          </tr>
```

I want to pass to the form the userid and the perm (permission), but if I print the values passed to the web server, I see that perm is always=0. Why? Where is the error in the js function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to happen when you create an element with the a tag name like "form_user_xxx".  The argument to "createElement" is supposed to be a tag name, like just plain "form".

Comment: Because I have a list of users and I want to assign the same permission at the entire list of users at one time. So I want to create in a for loop a form for every user. This notation is only to write dinamically every time "form_user_1", "form_user_2" ecc. It's python code inline. ;)

Comment: Also, for a `submit` call to pass values to the server, html elements with values mast have `name` attribute set.

Comment: @sharkbait well that's just not the way HTML works.

Comment: You think it's this the error? mmmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this line:

`var submitForm = document.createElement("form_user_{{ user.id }}");`

`form_user_{{ user.id }}` is not a valid html element. you need to pass `form` to the `createElement` method.

Comment: But my form has named form_user_{{ user.id }} , where {{user.id}} is every time a different number...

Comment: The function works. userid (newid.value = "{{ user.id }}";) is correctly passed.... so I thinked I'm wrong the grammar for passing the parameter in input of the function...

Comment: well. i just told you what is invalid about your code. you cannot create a form this way.

Comment: your dom node creation equals: `<form_user_{{ user.id }}></form_user_{{ user.id }}>`

Comment: So how can I do? Any idea?